# how can i can change the icon of the facebook app in the timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

[image]

See the above image, So i changed the tab image of the app using the instruction from this [site](http://www.facebook.com/help?faq=201402119964259). But i can't change this icon. How can change that.

Answer (score 2):

On the main page of the app in the developer settings, there is the an app image and some smaller text that says "edit icon" - this is what the small icon refers to and it is 16x16px. It's not related to the image that sits next to it which I believe is around 70x70px. The proximity does make it slightly confusing. But just click the text link

Comment: Where is the developer settings option in the main page of the app, I can't see it.

Comment: It's the first page you see when you edit an app. So on the left hand side it's called "basic" once you have clicked through to edit a specific app

Comment: Sorry TommyBs, I can't see any of the thing what you are saying. can you send me one image screenshot, then i can find easily.

Comment: Go to http://developers.facebook.com  Then click your app on the left hand side. Then on the far right (under the new "create new app" button) there is a link titled "edit settings" . Click this and it should take you to the "basic" settings of your app. Up the top of this page, it lists your app name, app_id and secret. Just underneath your app secret is a link labelled "edit icon"

Comment: You need to be the owner of the app to edit that small icon though. If you are not, then you cannot edit it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10793/discussion-between-suresh-pattu-and-tommybs)